# IPC mechanisms for python

Tags: python, ipc

A and B are two python programs in the same directory. Currently program A is running and now program B is going to be executed from A by using the following instruction.

```
os.system("python B.py & echi $!")
```

'A' has to execute 'B' for more than 100 times, but sometimes B will hang in between, so at that time I couldn't able to continue the whole operation. Now I want a IPC mechanism to find whether 'B' got struck, If it is strucked then I can kill that process automatically and start again.

NOTE: I don't want to use mmap,files, pickle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of os.system, you can use subprocess.Popen to create a subprocess and then use subprocess.Popen.poll to check at specific intervals to see if the child process has finished. If not you can kill it using subprocess.Popen.kill. For example you can wrap it in a function like this.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time

def process(*args):
    return_code, threshold = None, 5

    def reader():
        try:
            while 1:
                process.status_check_time = time.time()
                process.process.stdout.readline()
        except:
            pass

    try:
        return_code = process.process.poll()
        curr_time = time.time()

        if return_code != None:
            raise Exception()

        if curr_time - process.status_check_time > threshold:
            process.process.kill()
            raise Exception()
    except:
        process.process = subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize = 0, shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
        (threading.Thread(target = reader)).start()

    return return_code
```

Now calling `process('/path/to/your/program')` should (re)start your program based on the threshold given, 5 second in this case. To avoid restart the child process should print something to the stdout/stderr every 5 seconds.

Comment: Actually child process has to do a scrapping operation for whole day, So I should kill only if it got struct, I should  not kill blindly without knowing whether it is scraping or not.

Comment: then may be you can periodically write a status code from the child process and read it from the parent process. The read operation can be done in a separate thread and if nothing is read in fixed time period, the main thread can terminate the child process and start a new one.

Comment: In my program child process is scraping all the data from web, so it has to run for whole day. In between anything happens to that child process it will not return any value to its parent, it will simply hang without returning anything. So if it got struck in the middle, I have find out that. So how can I do this?